# Nested Coordinator+AppBar layout's not working

Tags: android

I just started working with `CoordinatorLayout` and AppBar. I have a layout **activity_home.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
                        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

                        <AutoCompleteTextView
                            android:id="@+id/ac_search"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                            android:focusable="true"
                            android:hint="@string/search"
                            android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
                            android:singleLine="true"
                            android:visibility="gone"/>

                    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/layout_search_results"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:visibility="gone"
                        android:orientation="vertical">
                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_margin="0dp"
                            android:background="@color/white"
                            android:orientation="horizontal"
                            android:paddingStart="@dimen/_6sdp"
                            android:paddingEnd="@dimen/_6sdp">

                            <CheckBox
                                android:id="@+id/cb_search_deals"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="50dp"
                                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_6sdp"
                                android:layout_weight="0.45"
                                android:button="@drawable/checkbox_button"
                                android:checked="true"
                                android:paddingStart="@dimen/_8sdp"
                                android:text="@string/Search_for_Deals"
                                android:textSize="13sp"/>

                            <View
                                android:layout_width="0.25dp"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:layout_weight="0.015"
                                android:background="@color/grey"/>

                            <CheckBox
                                android:id="@+id/cb_search_business"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="50dp"
                                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_12sdp"
                                android:layout_weight="0.50"
                                android:button="@drawable/checkbox_button"
                                android:paddingStart="@dimen/_8sdp"
                                android:text="@string/Search_for_Business"
                                android:textSize="13sp"/>
                        </LinearLayout>

                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:id="@+id/rl_search_results"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="50dp"
                            android:layout_gravity="start|center_vertical"
                            android:background="@color/red"
                            android:gravity="start|center_vertical">

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/tv_search_results"
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/iv_filter_results"
                                android:paddingStart="15dp"
                                android:text="Showing 10 Results"
                                android:textAllCaps="false"
                                android:textColor="@color/white"
                                android:textSize="14sp"
                                android:textStyle="normal"/>

                            <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/iv_filter_results"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                                android:src="@drawable/ic_filter"/>
                        </RelativeLayout>

                        <ListView
                            android:id="@+id/lv_search_results"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_margin="0dp"
                            android:divider="@color/white"
                            android:dividerHeight="0dp"
                            android:scrollbars="none"
                            android:visibility="visible"/>
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <FrameLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:paddingStart="@dimen/_12sdp"
                            android:paddingEnd="@dimen/_12sdp"
                            android:scrollbars="none"
                            android:background="@color/red"
                            app:tabTextColor="@color/tab_text_color"
                            app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/white"
                            app:tabMode="scrollable"
                            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/white"
                            app:tabTextAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Small" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="48dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/tabs_overlay" />

                    </FrameLayout>

                </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:visibility="gone"/>

                <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                    android:id="@+id/home_viewpager"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layoutDirection="locale"
                    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

            </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <include layout="@layout/layout_navigation"/>

        <include layout="@layout/layout_filter"/>

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

`ViewPager` with `id=home_viewpager` is the handling tablayout fragments.

It's working fine only on Lollipop because in code i have setted `listview.setNestedScrollEnabed(true)` but its NOT working on 4.2.2 also the first fragment of viewpager (listview with header) is getting cut off from bottom i.e Complete screen content is not shown.

In my second fragment of viewpager with layout name **fragment_top_deals**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white">


        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/banner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />

            <include
                layout="@layout/layout_filter_header"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/banner" />

      </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <com.app.views.MultiSwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipeRefreshLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_8sdp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/header"
        >

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:clickable="true"
            >

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/list_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scrollbars="none"
                android:divider="@null"
                android:dividerHeight="@dimen/_8sdp"
              app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/> 

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/empty_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/error_no_data"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:visibility="gone"/>

        </FrameLayout>

    </com.app.views.MultiSwipeRefreshLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>



    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/custom_progress"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

the problem is that the the `activity_home` coordinator layout + app bar effect is not working instead the `CoordinatorLayout` and Appbar of current layout is working fine. This implementation also not working on 4.2.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you noticed, `ListView` only supports nested scrolling (a requirement for `AppBarLayout` scrolling support) starting in Lollipop. Prior to that, you must use a view that implements [NestedScrollingChild](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/NestedScrollingChild.html) such as [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) or [NestedScrollView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/NestedScrollView.html).

Comment: Thanks Ian. Yes i understand `ListView` supports nested scrolling from `Lollipop`. But if you see my `activity_home` it has an `AppBarLayout` surrounding `Toolbar and Tabs` and `fragment_top_deals` also has `AppBarLayout` surronding ImageView and a layout. When i'm on TopDealsFragment tab the fragment's level effect of `AppBarLayout` is working and `ImageView` gets off the screen on scrolling up but the `Toolbar and Tabs` are not moving out of screen on scroll up which is part of `activity_home`. Please note activity_home's viewpager is hosting all the fragments of tab.

Comment: Also i have tried putting my `ListView` inside a `NestedScrollView` but has problem? Is `NestedScrollView` meant to be used this way or i may have misunderstood!

Comment: My point is that you'll never get scroll events from a pre-Lollipop ListView to work with AppBarLayout, etc. No matter if you wrap it in a NestedScrollView or not. Best to switch to RecyclerView, which works better everywhere

Comment: I'm talking about Lollipop!